# QMap Insert only produces (error) 0 for Value and Key

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qmap

I am having a problem inserting values into a QMap & I cannot figure out why. I have stripped my code right down to just make what I was trying to do work. The code is below:

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QString>
#include <QMap>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QString string1 = "a";
    QString string2 = "b";
    QMap<QString,QString> myMap;

    myMap.insert(string1,string2);

    return a.exec();
}
```

This produces the following map:
[image: output Map]

Why is this happening? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like you're using Visual Studio. Have you installed the plugin correctly?

Comment: I Haven't had any problems with anything else I have done QT-wise, I have also ensured that Core is selected within QT project settings.

Comment: This looks like a problem with the VS variable watch, that it is having trouble parsing the contents of the variable. Can you confirm (using QDebug) that the contents of `myMap` are indeed not correct?

Comment: *sigh*. Using QDebug it can access the key and give me the value. I just printed it to console. Can you answer the question with the above & i'll accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a problem with the VS variable watch, that it is having trouble parsing the contents of the variable.

If you check the values in `myMap` using QDebug(), you'll probably find that the pairs have inserted correctly but VS is not interpreting the contents correctly.

Try uninstalling and re-installing your VS plugin and, if the problem persists, log a bug with Qt that their `QMap` parsing script in the VS plugin might be faulty.